# Atualização no MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

Existe alguma função que permita enviar alguma mensagem quando algum dado for adicionado na collection?

Meio que um logs

**Por exemplo:**

```py
data = {
    "_id": 12345678910
}

return db.insert_one(data)
```

**Terminal**:

`Um novo documento foi adicionado na collection!:`
"_id": 12345678910

Comment: pq voce nao adiciona uma funcao no seu backend, ao adicionar a collection envia uma notificacao algo do tipo

Answer (score 0):

Com as informações que você forneceu fica praticamente impossível te responder. Explico:

1) Você não deu nenhuma informação sobre o contexto (você vai incluir um documento na `collection` e quer saber se o documento foi corretamente inserido? Ou um outro usuário vai adicionar um documento e você quer enviar uma notificação para ele? Entre outras diversas opções...)

2) Na sua pergunta você cita `collection`, mas no seu exemplo você usa a `database`. Você quer saber se um documento foi inserido na `collection` ou na `database` como um todo?

Se você estiver inserindo e quiser checar que a operação foi bem-sucedida, considere checar `acknowledged` e se você consegue acessar o id do novo documento.

```
>>> new_document = collection.insert_one({'teste0': 'teste0'})
>>> new_document.acknowledged
True
>>> print(new_document.inserted_id)
5d8df5f3d6866c94867acc3b
```

De acordo com a [documentação oficial](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.InsertOneResult.acknowledged), `acknowledged == False` indica que todos os outros atributos da classe acusarão `InvalidOperation` quando acessados.

É claro que você também pode usar a mesma lógica quando inserir mais de um documento na mesma operação:

```
>>> new_documents = collection.insert_many([{'teste1': 'teste1'}, {'teste2': 'teste2'}])
>>> new_documents.acknowledged
True
>>> for id in new_documents.inserted_ids:
...     print(id)
...
5d8df7a3d6866c94867acc3c
5d8df7a3d6866c94867acc3d
```

De fato, você até pode tentar prever outros erros quando for realizar uma operação. Uma abordagem bem genérica é a seguinte:

```
try:
    #Qualquer uma de suas operações
except pymongo.errors.PyMongoError as erro:
    logging.error(f'Erro inesperado com o Mongo: {erro.__class__};\n{erro}')
    #Código para tratar alguma exceção genérica
```

`pymongo.errors.PyMongoError` é [classe base para todas as exceções do pymongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/errors.html#pymongo.errors.PyMongoError).

Se você não tiver acesso direto a operação, considere usar [`count_documents`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.count_documents):

```
>>> num_docs = collection.count_documents({})
#Como não passamos nenhum filtro, checamos todos os documentos da collection
>>> num_docs
7
...
...
...
...
'''
Checando se um novo documento foi inserido
'''
>>> new_num_docs = collection.count_documents({})
>>> if new_num_docs > num_docs: #Novo documento inserido!
...     print('Um novo documento foi adicionado.')
...     print(new_num_docs, num_docs)
...
Um novo documento foi adicionado.
8 7
```

Comment: Queria fazer com que cada documento adicionado na collection(db) fosse printada algo no terminal

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo melhor

Comment: Como, por onde e por quem os documentos vão ser adicionados?